# How to cut word in java before and after space

Tags: java

Can you help me with this, please?
I would like to get only specified WORD from the below String.

```
String test1="This is WORD test".
```

I did this:

```
String regex = "\\s*\\bWORD\\b\\s*";
Text= test1.replaceAll(regex, " ");
```

and I get this: `This is test`

But what I want is the opposite: I want only the part matching the regex.

Sometime my String could be:

```
String test2="WORD it is the text"
String test3="Text WORD"
```

But all the time I would like to cut only specified word and put into other string. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but i found question unclear. What is expected output per case?

Comment: Why not just use replaceAll(your_word, " ") ?

Comment: You seem to know how to use regex, but have you looked at `Pattern` and `Matcher`, especially the [`group`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group()) method

Comment: If you already know which word you want to extract, why do you want to extract it at all? Adding some example inputs and expected outputs would be helpful.

Comment: Problem is that I'm checking later if one string containg second for instance: test1.contains("WORD) and this test1 contains but I would like to have true only if I have one WORD.contains("WORD"). Not sure if it clear...

Comment: It is for dropdown option

Comment: If you already know what WORD is why do you have to get it from the string? Just check if WORD is in the string.

Comment: What the turtles are saying!

Comment: yes, but what if I would like to select only that option where I have only one exactly this: WORD

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using regular expression where I only check for the word being either surrounded by space or at the beginning of the line with space after or at the end of the line with space before.

```
String regex = "( WORD )|(^WORD )|( WORD$)";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(test1);

if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("[" + m.group(0).trim() + "]");
}
```

Comment: @gadhet Any feedback on this?

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**

A possible way to solve this

```
String test1 = "This is WORD test";
String wordToFind = "WORD";
String message = "";

int k = 0;

for (int i = -1; (i = test1.indexOf(wordToFind, i + 1)) != -1; i++) {
    k = i;
}

String s = test1.substring(k, k+ (wordToFind.length()));
if(s.equals(wordToFind)){
    message = s;
} else {
    message = "The word \"" + wordToFind + "\" was not found in \"" + test1 + "\"";
}

System.out.print(message);
```

Comment: Or shorter: `if(test.indexOf("WORD) != -1) print("WORD)`

Comment: Try with "sWORD".

Comment: @JoakimDanielson good point, if the word is not found then it output the substring on k index. Look the edited version

Comment: Did you try your code yourself? For me "sWORD" prints "WORD".

Comment: For me it prints `This` and if the `wordToFind` gets bigger, it outputs the following words